# sqlmetal.exe returns Using the generic type 'System.Data.Linq.Table' requires 1 type arguments

Tags: c#, reference, type-inference, sqlmetal

I am using sqlmetal.exr to generate the mapping code for me. I am calling sql metal by using.

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin
SqlMetal.exe /server:servername\SQL /database:mydb /code:mycode.cs
```

The output is a cs file and the command promt says:

> Microsoft (R) Database Mapping Generator 2008 version 1.00.30729 for
>   Microsoft (R) .NET Framework version 3.5 Copyright (C) Microsoft
>   Corporation. All rights reserved.

When I add the file to my project and try to build it I get the following error:

> Using the generic type 'System.Data.Linq.Table' requires 1 type
>   arguments

This is in my mycode.cs file. I am referencing System.Data.Linq and System.Data. What referennce is missing to get this to work?

**Update**

> Make sure you have System.Data.Linq in your GAC and that the assembly
>   version is 3.5.0.0. Also make sure that's the version your project is
>   referencing.

[image]

[image]

> Double-check that your application's target framework hasn't somehow
>   been changed to something other than 3.5. The Linq To SQL features
>   only work with the 3.5 framework.

[image]

Comment: are you doing any Linq to SQl or anything like that..? are you using any Linq Statements at all in your code..? if not remove the using System.Linq from the header of the .cs file(s)

Comment: Yes I am doing Linq to SQL and there are Linq statments inmy code.

Comment: ok when you compile the project.. is the System.Data.Linq in the GAC..?

Comment: Yes System.Data.Linq is in the GAC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the problem persist here are a list of things you can try to resolve the issue

A few things to check/try:

- Make sure you have System.Data.Linq in your GAC and that the assembly version is 3.5.0.0. Also make sure that's the version your project is referencing.
- When you look at the project references is there a yellow "!" icon next to the reference? If so, that indicates that the version of System.Data.Linq your project references is not being found by VS. You should try deleting the reference and adding a new one.
- Double-check that your application's target framework hasn't somehow been changed to something other than 3.5. The Linq To SQL features only work with the 3.5 framework.

Comment: Thanks updated the question with the answer to these points. All seem fine but still not working. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Set Copy Local to True and see if that helps.. there must be an issue that when you deploy it.. the version of System.Data.Linq is not on that target system.. also look at the Path.. that's the path of your Local as well you can't assume that the target path is the same as your local path..